# Calling classes from different projects without causing a Circular Reference

Tags: .net-core

I have a solution, with multiple projects. The ones that concern us here are the Website project and the Models project.

The models have a lot of models in Request/Response mode. E.g. If I have a method called GetCustomers, it will be declared like this public GetCustomersResponse GetCustomers(GetCustomersRequest req). This will make sure that if more params are added in the future, I just need to update the model. Hope you get the idea.

All the req/res models are inheriting a baseReq and baseRes respectively. One of the properties included here is called Header, which includes a number of common properties (e.g. SiteId, Currency).

For each Request, I have to call an Initialize method to fill these properties for me (located in the Website project (due to HttpRequest info required). Would it be possible to call this method from the Model project itself (in the constructor), so as to avoid calling the initialize (code repetition) each time? As it is, since the Website referencing the Models, it is not possible to go back due to Circular reference. Is there a way around it, or is it just not possible?

I have tried to look at different articles on the web, but most say that this is just not possible. Others suggested to have a third project, where both projects reference it, but not sure if this works, since I need the HttpContext object.

Any ideas please? Alternatively would I be able to access the HttpContext from within the Models project?

Comment: _Alternatively would I be able to access the HttpContext from within the Models project_ - Yes, `HttpContext` is part of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` library which can be accessed from both Web or Model projects. Notice, I am saying only that it is possible, I am not saying this is correct way of doing it ;)

Comment: What @Fabio said and refactor the initialization code into the Models project?

Comment: Look at the Dependency Injection pattern for .Net and the HttpAccessor https://rion.io/2016/01/04/accessing-identity-info-using-dependency-injection-in-net-5/